# Flutter widget tests with platform branching

Tags: flutter

In my widget's code I need to branch on Android/iOS to show widgets specific to each platform, and also call platform specific APIs (e.g. the Android widget will call an API only available on Android).

```
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    return WidgetAndroid(...);
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    return WidgetIOS(...);
  }
```

How can I test that the right widget is shown using a Flutter widget test?

I know I can check that the widget exists but how do I run the test with a specific platform.

```
expect(find.byType(WidgetIOS), findsOneWidget);
```

Comment: https://dev.to/arthurdenner/write-and-test-platform-specific-widgets-in-flutter-1f4l

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In 2022 it is not recommended to use `dart:io` and `Platform` class to determine the runtime platform. The better alternative is to use `defaultTargetPlatform` available through 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'. I.e.:

```
if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android ||
            defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {}
```

Should you have that approach for determining platform in your code overiding platform in tests is as easy as setting `debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride` in your test body.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride.html

E.g.:

```
  testWidgets('DataTable2 renders with DataRow.index()',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.android;
 ...
    debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = null;
  });
```

Comment: Please provide source to support claim "it is not recommended to use Platform from dart:io after 2022", otherwise it is misleading. According to docs of `defaultTargetPlatform`: _The [TargetPlatform] that matches the platform on which the framework is currently executing_, while `Platform` from `dart:io`: _Information about the environment in which the current program is running._ Two completely different purposes of different variables.

Comment: `dart:io` can't be used in the Web, any project that has this import and doesn't use conditional imports won't compile for Web platform

Comment: Good point and fair enough, although this doesn't necessarily mean it is "not recommended" to use certain API. Thanks for answering! 

Comment: Well, it is recomended cause it gives the same capabilities, has widest platform support and doesn't introduce any implicit constraints on supported platfroms ;)

Answer (score 11):

Both `Platform.isAndroid` and `Platform.isIOS` return `false` when running `testWidgets`.

Some suggestions we can apply in our tests:

- Pass the platform as variable to your top level Widget, that way you will be able to provide that value manually.
- Make the case you want to test an `else` without `if`, so that will run during the tests.
- Use instead `Platform` from https://pub.dev/packages/platform which allows mocking, which is probably the best long term solution.

Answer (score 3):

`Platform` is in `dart:io`, which is lower-level than Flutter's `TargetPlatform`. In most cases, you should use the latter.

From [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/defaultTargetPlatform.html):

> The [dart:io.Platform] object should only be used directly when it's critical to actually know the current platform, without any overrides possible (for example, when a system API is about to be called).

Answer (score 1):

Like Miguel mentioned you can't mock it directly.

If you use the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) framework, you can use dependency injection in your tests to make this happen without exposing an additional param in your widget.

Create an class to use for injection:

```
class PlatformInfo {
  final bool isIos;
  final bool isAndroid;

  PlatformInfo({@required this.isAndroid,@required  this.isIos});
}
```

in your top level `MultiProvider` widget, set up your provider bindings:

```
Provider<PlatformInfo>.value(
    value: PlatformInfo(isAndroid: Platform.isAndroid, isIos: Platform.isIOS),
),
```

Use it in your widget:

```
Provider.of<PlatformInfo>(context).isIos
```